# Block drop key for a certain item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, a while ago I dropped my valuable power tool in the nether by accidentally pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> and it fell into the lava so I needed to craft and upgrade a new one. Of course I don't want that to happen again. My question is if it would be possible to block the drop key for the power tool so that when I press <kbd>Q</kbd> it doesn't drop, but when I press it with an other item in my hand, for example dirt, the dirt blocks would still drop. I am using the  *direwolf20* modpack.

Comment: or remap drop item to another key on the other side of the keyboard

Comment: I pretty sure it can't be done, or you need a mod made specially for this.

Comment: @ratchetfreak This would be a simple solution but still not safe and also a bit painful for dropping lager quantities, also in the direwolf20 modpack there are so much keys which are already bound, some by multiple mods, so there are not many where you can bind it to.

Comment: the delete key is available, also it's safer to drop items from your inventory (click outside the UI)

Comment: @Arperum If it would be a client side mod where you can still play on multiplayer servers (if it blocks your Q key it probably is) I would use it.

Comment: @andalur I didn't say there is such a mod, I was merely saying that you'd NEED such a mod. You'll need to find someone who wants to make a mod specially for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not possible** to do that in vanilla Minecraft. Minecraft doesn't care what type of item it is, and will throw it all the same. It wouldn't be too difficult creating a mod which only lets you drop blocks, not tools, but you would need to contact a modder for this feature; as far as I know there are no existing mods with this capability.

I have run into this same problem, and have avoided the issue by going into the settings and changing the "drop item" key to something like <kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>P</kbd>, making it much more difficult to hit the key by accident.

Comment: If you are interested, remind me when MCP has updated to 1.7, and I can try to hammer out a quick mod for this feature. But I would still recommend remapping the key anyway.